# Extract and merge strings between different positions

Tags: php, arrays, substr

I'm trying to make this works. I want to replace some parts of a sentence between given positions and then show the full sentence with the changes. With the following code, I'm able to make the changes but I don't know how to put together the rest of the sentence.

I have two arrays, one with the positions where a woman name appears and another one with men names. The code replaces the pronoun "his" by "her" when a woman is before a man between the intervals. The last thing I need is to reconstruct the sentence with the changes made but I don't know how to extract the rest of the sentence (the result, in the example, is from positions 0 to 20 (Maria her dress but) and 36 to 51 (Lorena her dog) but I need to extract from 20 to 36 (Peter his jeans) and 51 to the end (Juan his car) to merge them in their positions).

The result should be: "Maria her dress but Peter his jeans Lorena her dog Juan his car". I'll appreciate any help with this, I've been looking for other similar questions but I found nothing.

```
<?php

$womenpos  = array("0","36"); //these arrays are just examples of positions
$menpos    = array("20","51"); //they will change depending on the sentence
$sentence  = "Maria his dress but Peter his jeans Lorena his dog Juan his car";

echo $sentence."\n";      


foreach ($womenpos as $index => $value) {
    $value2 = $menpos[$index];      

    if($value < $value2) {
        echo "\nWoman(" . $value . ") is before man(" . $value2 . ")\n";
        $end = ($value2 - $value);
        $improved = str_replace(' his ', ' her ', 
                         substr($sentence, $value, $end));                           

        echo $improved."\n";                 

    } else {
        $improved = "Nothing changed";
     echo $improved;
    }     

}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you asking.

Comment: I have updated the question with a (hopefully) better explanation.

Comment: important question: are you trying to replace the word 'his' for 'her' (if so, a regular expression replacement without any positional information works just fine. That's a oneliner) or are you trying to replace data in a sentence based on position+length, in which case you just need do substring splits and then join them on your replacements

Comment: You don't do it in the right way. Scan the sentence word by word, and dump it. When you read a name, store the gender, update next his/her and so on

Comment: I need the positions because I need to the make the changes just in the cases when a woman's name is before a man's

Comment: @Ôrel Before this part of the code, I have scanned the sentence to store the positions of each name.

Comment: So why not directly do the modification ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, how about this:

```
$womenpos  = array("0","36");
$menpos    = array("20","51");
$bothpos   = array_merge($womenpos,$menpos);
sort ($bothpos);
print_r($bothpos);

$sentence  = "Maria his dress but Peter his jeans Lorena his dog Juan his car";

echo $sentence."\n";      

for ($i = 0; $i<sizeof($bothpos); $i++) {
    $start = $bothpos[$i];
    if ($i ==sizeof($bothpos)-1) {
        $end = strlen($sentence);
    }
    else {
        $end = $bothpos[$i+1];
    }
    $length = $end-$start;
    $segment = substr($sentence, $start, $length);
    if (in_array($start, $womenpos)) {
        $new_segment = str_replace (' his ', ' her ', $segment);
    }
    else { $new_segment = $segment; }
    $improved .= $new_segment; 
    print "<li>$start-$end: $segment :  $new_segment </li>\n";
}

print "<p>Improved: $improved</p>";
```

This combines the men's and women's position arrays to consider each stretch of text as one that might have an error. If that stretch of text starts at one of the womenpos points, then it changes 'his' to 'her'. If not it leaves it alone.

Does this get you in the direction you want to go in? I hope so!

Comment: That's what I exactly was trying to do but I would never be able to think about one solution like that. Thanks Ken!!

Answer (score 0):

This approaches the problem differently, but I wonder if it would provide the solution you're looking for:

```
$sentence  = "Maria his dress but Peter his jeans Lorena his dog Juan his car";

$women = array ("Maria", "Lorena");

$words = explode (" ", $sentence);

for ($i=0; $i< sizeof($words); $i++) {
    if ($words[$i] == "his" && in_array($words[$i-1], $women)) {
        $words[$i] = "her";
    }
}

print (join(" ", $words));
```

This goes through the words one at a time; if the preceding word is in the $women array and the current word is "his", it changes the word to "her". Then it spits out all the words in order.

Does this do what you need, or do you really want a complex string positioning answer?

Comment: The problem with your option is that isn't  going to be always the preceding word, the sentence is just an example, the pronoun could be in any other position of the sentence like "Maria washed his car and John his bike"

Comment: We could certainly come up with a solution that relies on string positioning, but wouldn't that require that the person writing the code already knew the positions of the problematic strings? 

Do you want the code to be able to detect problems, or only respond to problem strings that the coder knows about?

Comment: I already have the code which store the positions for the problematic strings, delivering two arrays: one for female's names and the other one for man's. What I don't know is how to remake the sentence once I have made the changes.